# How to replace &ndash with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, json, api

I'm getting JSON back from an API, and when the article text returns, alot of times there will be a dash.  But the dash comes thru as `&ndash` instead how the actual `-`...

How do I convert the `&ndash` to just the actual `-`?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tell your server people not to send crappy pseudo-xml escaped characters back in JSON which doesn't require them to be escaped and to send the actual character back instead in some sane encoding, like UTF-8.

Comment: Ha!  I wish I could tell them, but its a big media company API, so i don't have that pull with them :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 NSString *myString = @"Here is &ndash some text";
 myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&ndash" withString:@"-"];
```

Comment: You rock, thats perfect!

Comment: And once I get up to 15 reputation points I'll be able to upvote your answer too :)

Comment: @MATTHEWNOAKES Just be careful with this because it's really not very efficient, although it's the only way to do the job. Too bad you can't get them to deal with it on the server :)

Comment: That is a fair point. Just make sure you aren't replacing a bunch of different things and I think you'll be ok.

Comment: For more extensive replacement (of correctly-encoded entities, anyways -- this one is missing the semicolon terminator), [a category on NSString](https://github.com/woolsweater/NSString-WSSHTMLEntityConversion) to do them all at once might be recommended.

Comment: @JasonCoco I'll put a request in with them to open up a ticket for it for sure now, thanks for the heads up and the help

Comment: @squarefrog thanks for the input, helpful to get insight since this is my first time using it

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks for the link, looks like a good resource for me to use